# VS2017 does not support binary fold?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17

Why doesn't the following compile?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
void print_all( Args&&... args )
{
    std::cout << ... << args;
}

int main()
{
    print_all( 1, 2, 3, std::endl );
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following errors in VS2017 15.9.7, with /std:c++17

```
error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token '...', expected 'expression'
error C2660: 'print_all': function does not take 4 arguments
```

Second error goes away if I remove std::endl, but first error occurs with any use of binary fold expression, no matter the operator. According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019), my version of VS should support fold operators.

Comment: The parentheses are part of a fold expression, you can't remove them. Use `(std::cout << ... << args);`.

Comment: _"... Second error goes away if I remove std::endl..."_: `std::endl` is a template not a vanilla function https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have to admit that I dont know if VS 15.9.7 supports fold expression. However, you get the error because `std::cout << ... << args;` is not a [fold-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). The correct syntax would be

```
(std::cout << ... << args);
```

Further note that `std::endl` is a template function, and thus you cannot simply pass it the way you do (hence the second error).